# Meteor login email domain predefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, accounts

I want to make a Meteor app where users can only create an account if their email ends with @mydomain.com.

In the end, they would actually only need to enter their username and not the @mydomain.com part.

So, the create user field would look like:

```
Name:       __________
eMail:      __________@mydomain.com
Password:   __________
Renter:     __________
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You use accounts package: `meteor add accounts-password`.
Then you would configure it in server-side code (http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config): `Accounts.config({restrictCreationByEmailDomain:'mydomain.com'});`

And then use `Accounts.createUser` in combination with custom UI that autofills the email domain part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Meteor's built-in accounts management packages. To limit signups to `mydomain.com` email addresses, put the following in server-side code:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function(user) {
  if (/@mydomain\.com$/.test(user.emails[0].address.toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Email domain not allowed.");
  }
});
```

As for helping them with adding the `@mydomain.com`, write some client-side code that validates the field in the login form where they enter their username. If it lacks an `@`, tack `@mydomain.com` onto the end of it before the form gets submitted.